# Calculate NPath complexity for try-catch-finally

Tags: java, complexity-theory, static-analysis

I've read article "NPATH: A MEASURE OF EXECUTION PATH COMPLEXITY AND ITS APPLICATIONS" Nejmeh, Communications of the ACM Feb 1988 pp 188-200, it says nothing about NPath complexity for try-catch-finally statement.

The formula I deduced is

```
NP(T-C-F) = (NP(try-range) + S(NP(catch)))*NP(finally),
```

where

```
NP(finally) = NP(finally-range) or 1, if no finally block range is present,
```

and

```
NP(catch) = NP(catch-range)
```

(Here is an interesting side question if java multicatch should be counted as catch with multiple branches with NP(catch-expr) added to its complexity.)

My knowledge of subject field of CS is quite low, so I am not sure is my formula is correct or if the concept of NPath complexity is applicable to  exception handling code.

Comment: This isn't programming, this is CS theory, and should be on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the description they put for the article :"Software engineering is a discipline in search of objective measures for factors that contribute to software quality. NPATH, which counts the acyclic execution paths through a function, is an objective measure of software complexity related to the ease with which software can be comprehensively tested." , so i don't think this is just about CS theory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is CS theory, and should be on cs.stackexchange.com